# Unity : 3d Model Movement according to platform spawning

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity and started creating a simple zigzag game. The platforms initially spawn in the X and Z directions and the player changes direction on screen tap in X and Z directions.

After, lets say, spawning of 30 platforms, I switch the platform spawning to -X and Z axis. How do I inform my 3d model that now on screen tap, it has to change directions in -X and Z axis.

I have written the code but the problem occurs that I am not able to tell my character when the direction switch occurs. So it happens that the platforms are still spawning in X and Z axis, but my character now moves in -X and Z axis.

How do I bring platform spawning and character directions in sync?

**CODE**

Here is the code for platform spawning

```
 void SpawnPlatform() {

 if(score  < 30)
 {
  int rand = Random.Range(0, 6);
  if (rand < 3)
  {
     SpawnX();
  }
  else if(rand >= 3)
  {
     SpawnZ();
  }
 }
if(score > 30)
{
  int rand = Random.Range(0, 6);
  if (rand < 3)
  {
     SpawnNegX();
  }
  else if(rand >= 3)
  {
     SpawnZ();
  }
}

void SpawnX()
{
  Vector3 pos = lastPos;
  pos.x += size;
  lastPos = pos;
  Instantiate(platform, pos, Quaternion.identity);

  int rand = Random.Range(0, 4);
  if (rand < 1)
  {
      Instantiate(diamonds, new Vector3(pos.x,pos.y+1,pos.z), 
      diamonds.transform.rotation);
  }
}

 void SpawnNegX()
 {
 Vector3 pos = lastPos;
 pos.x -= size;
 lastPos = pos;
 Instantiate(platform, pos, Quaternion.identity);

 int rand = Random.Range(0, 4);
 if (rand < 1)
 {
     Instantiate(diamonds, new Vector3(pos.x,pos.y+1,pos.z), 
     diamonds.transform.rotation);
 }

 }

 void SpawnZ()
 {
 Vector3 pos = lastPos;
 pos.z += size;
 lastPos = pos;
 Instantiate(platform, pos, Quaternion.identity);

 int rand = Random.Range(0, 4);
 if (rand < 1)
 {
     Instantiate(diamonds, new Vector3(pos.x, pos.y + 1, pos.z), 
     diamonds.transform.rotation);
 }
}
```

and this for the character controller. The issue is here. how do i inform the character that now switch directions between -X and Z instead of X and Z.

```
 void Update () {
 if (!started)
 {
     if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
     {
         rb.velocity = new Vector3(speed, 0, 0);
     }
 }

 if (!Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Vector3.down, 1f))
 {
     rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, -25f, 0);
 }

 if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && !gameOver)
 {
     SwitchDirection();
 }
}

 void SwitchDirection()
 {
 if (rb.velocity.z > 0)
 {
     rb.velocity = new Vector3(speed, 0, 0);
 }else if(rb.velocity.x > 0)
 {
     rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, speed);
 }
}
```

I am replicating the classic zigzag game but spawning platforms in the other directions as well. so it looks like the original game for now.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3Iz8.jpg)

Comment: Are you using this function to switch directions SwitchDirection()? and after what lines of the Spawning code you would like to perfom this switch? I gave you an answer of how to invoke a method from one script to another, but to make it work properly I will need to know exactly when and where you are implementing this direction switch.

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre  say the first 30 platforms are spawned in -x direction. so the character moves -x on tap. and from 31 to 60, platforms spawn in X direction. so 31st platform is when the character should be notified about the switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are spawning multiple platforms ahead, possibly in `Z+`, `X-` or `X+` you cannot just make a bool to flip X after spawning the first `-X` platform.

You need to know where the next platform is. Or better, if there is a platform in `X+` or not.

My approach uses [Physics.Checkbox](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.CheckBox.html) to check (a Raycast would work too), the platforms need a boxcollider for this to work.

[image]

Code:

```
void SwitchDirection()
{
   if (rb.velocity.z > 0)
   {
       bool platformInXplus = Physics.CheckBox(transform.position + Vector3.right * size, Vector3.one * .1f + Vector3.up * 2f, Quaternion.identity, /*layermask*/ 0, QueryTriggerInteraction.UseGlobal); 

       if(platformInXplus)
       {
           rb.velocity = new Vector3(speed, 0, 0);
       }
       else
       {
           rb.velocity = new Vector3(-speed, 0, 0);
       }
   }
   else if(Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.x) > 0f)
   {
       rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, speed);
   }
}
```

If you have more colliders in your game, you can put the platforms on a layer and use a proper  [layermask](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html) in `CheckBox`. (To avoid checking your Diamonds for example)

edit: I changed `rb.velocity.x > 0` because this is no longer true in all cases. I use the absolute now to check if we are moving in `X+` OR `X-`.

edit2: I changed the CheckBox size to `Vector3.one * .1f + Vector3.up * 2f`

edit3: If you stand very far left on a platform, the checkBox might hit the current platform. You might want to round the player position first, to snap to the platform-grid (so you start centered on the current platform, then check `size` units to the right)

so it's `(.1, 2.1, .1)` to make sure you hit platforms, even if the player origin is above it.

Comment: Thanks @KYL3R.. I'll implement and let you know if this did the trick. Thanks mate!! cheers

Comment: Thanks a lot @KYL3R for the explanation with the diagram. Really makes sense now. Will implement it tonight. Will keep you posted if it works. Thanks for the help and keep up the good work. Cheers Mate!!!

Comment: After that explanation with the image, I might go ahead and implement -X and X and also -Z and Z as well. Gave me the confidence I needed. :)

Comment: I think that would still play well. For the user it's still "one-tap-control" - very simple! Only the "toggle" is different. But be careful with that random platform generation, avoid 2x2 patterns or placing platforms IN existing platforms. You may use the `checkBox` while generating, too - to verify the spot is free

Comment: Yes i have taken that into account as well. (using this while generating platforms as well). Thanks :)

Comment: i was able to achieve change direction from your code. Thanks for the help. Can you tell me how do I avoid 2x2 platform generation. It always generates 2x2 when I switch direction in platform spawning.

Comment: I would count the Z-spawned and X(plus)Spawned platforms. But that **could** still create unwanted shapes. The `checkBox` code could test for collision on the existing platforms and avoid any unwanted neighbouring.

Answer (score 0):

*problem occurs that I am not able to tell my character when the direction switch occurs.*

You just need to refer the player-script from the platform spawing-script and inform it that the direction has changed.

You already have got the function created in player: `SwitchDirection()`, so you can add this in the Spawing script.

In the inspector you will need to link the player with the Spawing script (In the Inspector Drag and Drop the Player GameObject over the mPlayer variable field in the Spawing script)

```
public GameObject mPlayer;
PlayerScript mPlayerScript;

Start(){
    mPlayerScript = mPlayer.GetComponent<PlayerScript>();
}
```

Update based on your comment: *say the first 30 platforms are spawned in -x direction. so the character moves -x on tap. and from 31 to 60, platforms spawn in X direction. so 31st platform is when the character should be notified about the switch* Later, where you are increasing the score you do this:

```
if(score%30 == 0)
{
    mPlayerScript.SwitchDirection()
}
```

Comment: Never played zig-zag, but I assume you spawn multiple platforms ahead. So you are on platform 5 and you alerady spawned 5 more. Your code would switch after spawning the first negative X platform, but you are still 5 platforms away from that.

Comment: @KYL3R well actually what I was trying was to explain him how to inform the player from the spawing script that it should change the direction. I will need to ask him exactly when the switch should take place, to adapt the code. I have to admit I never played that game neither.

Comment: This will probably still cause an issue as stated by KYL3R. The platform spawning is way ahead of the character running. So I cant just use score as an index to switch directions. (Score was my initial assumption but later I realised how horribly bad idea it was. I just posted my original code).

Comment: If you google images it seems that you walk on a path of random X / Z Tiles and just toggle walking direction. The simple toggle no longer works if you have -X platforms, too. This is where OPs question comes into play.

Comment: @ignacio allore say the first 30 platforms are spawned in -x direction. so the character moves -x on tap. and from 31 to 60, platforms spawn in X direction. so 31st platform is when the character should be notified about the switch.

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre well your answer does solve some of my issues. Thanks mate!!

Comment: @UdaykiranBitla I assumed you already have that working, and your problem was that you were not able to inform the player when to switch directions. So I replied to what you asked in the question, not to how to implement the other part.